# Angular select within a ng-repeat directive: how can I access the children scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select2

I've got an `ng-repeat`-ed table row, inside wich are a pair of angular `select`s:

```
    <div ng-controller="midiCtrl" id="midi-ctrl">
        [...]

                <tr ng-repeat="plugin in plugins">
                    <td><strong>{{plugin.name}}</strong></td>
                    <td>
                       <select class="span1" ng-model="selectedChannel" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in channels">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="span2" ng-model="selectedDevice" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in devices">
                    </td>
                </tr>

        [...]
    </div>
```

The controller is:

```
    app.controller('midiCtrl', function ($scope, pluginDisplayedWindows) {

        $scope.plugins = pluginDisplayedWindows.pluginsDisplayed; // An object          

        $scope.channels = [
           {ID: 'all', Title: 'All'},
           {ID: '0', Title: '1'},
           {ID: '1', Title: '2'},
           {ID: '2', Title: '3'}
        ];

        $scope.devices = [
           {ID: '0', Title: 'Device A'},
           {ID: '1', Title: 'Device B'},
           {ID: '2', Title: 'Device C'},
           {ID: '3', Title: 'Device D'},
        ];

    });
```

Now, I know that when one of the selects is selected, the corresponding object is set on the ng-model scope variable (`$scope.selectedChannel` or `$scope.selectedDevice`), but obviously it is set ***in the corresponding ng-repeat child scope***.

How can I access the children scopes, in the controller? I want to save all the selections when the user presses a button, but if I try to do that in the `midiCtrl` controller, I can't access to the children scopes created by `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest trick is to add the selected values to current `plugin` object, so you can easily get the selected values and those values are bound to the correct `plugin` object naturally. No other objects will be introduced. Very simple.

```
<select class="span1" ng-model="plugin.selectedChannel" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in channels">
<select class="span2" ng-model="plugin.selectedDevice" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in devices">
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/fa2Sw/)**</kbd>

If you want store it separately, you can do

```
<select class="span1" ng-model="selected[$index].selectedChannel" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in channels" />
<select class="span2" ng-model="selected[$index].selectedDevice" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in devices" />

$scope.selected = [];
angular.forEach($scope.plugins, function (a) {
    $scope.selected.push({
        selectedChannel: undefined,
        selectedDevice: undefined
    });
})
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/DPTtX/)**</kbd>

Comment: Really brilliant. It works because the children inherit the parent scope, doesn't it?

Comment: @janesconference as well as the current `plugin` object is tracked by reference. So the change like adding new properties to it from the child scope will be preserved.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if I wanted to use another object without "polluting" the plugin object?

Comment: Wow. I didn't know I could access the index right in the model. Thanks, extremely illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the selected object in the parent controller first. Objects you data-bind should always "have a dot" in them to avoid issues with prototypical inheritance, so you should bind to something like "selected.channel" rather than "selectedChannel"

```
app.controller('midiCtrl', function ($scope, pluginDisplayedWindows) {

$scope.plugins = pluginDisplayedWindows.pluginsDisplayed; // An object     


$scope.selected = {};
$scope.selected.channel = {};
$scope.selected.device = {};

$scope.channels = [
   {ID: 'all', Title: 'All'},
   {ID: '0', Title: '1'},
   {ID: '1', Title: '2'},
   {ID: '2', Title: '3'}
];

$scope.devices = [
   {ID: '0', Title: 'Device A'},
   {ID: '1', Title: 'Device B'},
   {ID: '2', Title: 'Device C'},
   {ID: '3', Title: 'Device D'},
];

});
```

And update the HTML accordingly

```
   <div ng-controller="midiCtrl" id="midi-ctrl">
        [...]

            <tr ng-repeat="plugin in plugins">
                <td><strong>{{plugin.name}}</strong></td>
                <td>
                   <select class="span1" ng-model="selected.channel" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in channels">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="span2" ng-model="selected.device" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in devices">
                </td>
            </tr>

    [...]
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. When one of the select is set, the other is set as well.